# Jquery animate ready to be triggered again

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have this basic JQuery code, I'm doin some testing with in order to learn and include something similar on a project, alter:

```
$("#content").on('scroll',function(event){

     if($(this).scrollTop() > 50) {
    $('#content img').animate({'top':'-100px'},2000);
     }
      if($(this).scrollTop() < 50) {
        $('#content img').animate({'top':'+100px'},2000);
       }
});
```

My actual problem is that on scroll down for example, it animates properly by moving the image down to 100px.
So far, so good.
But if you scroll down again...it doesnt happen again, it simply scroll like the normal html.

Any way to get the slow movement down ready again after the first one was triggered?

Comment: unclear what you are asking a jsfiddle would be better.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/hzg9Q/1/
But there is no picture and the #content::-webkit-scrollbar { } works only in the browser

Comment: thanks,please check answer, i figured out the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it, I had to make my own fiddle (not exactly what you wanted but the fix still stands on its own).

To fix the problem, use += and -= instead of + and -

```
$('#content img').animate({'top':'-=100px'},2000);
```

and

```
$('#content img').animate({'top':'+=100px'},2000);
```

---

i included my fiddle i used to test, if interested

[My Fiddle is a little different, but it still works multiple times](http://jsfiddle.net/qww56/1/)

UPDATE

```
var newTop = $('img').offset().top - $(window).scrollTop();
var newBottom = newTop + $('img').height();
```

Comment: Gosh, it was as simple as that...Grrrr and it was something I knew!!
I will take advantage of this post to ask if there is a way to make it stop once we reach the bottom of the image. Otherwise the image keeps goin up and disappear.
Thx!